# Replacing : in DATETIME in Python for api request

Tags: python, api, encoding

I see a lot of documentation around transforming datetime in python, I do know know how to search for what I understand to be encoding/decoding of datetime values, in order to make a python request:

the request accepts the below:

```
%5Bgt%5D=2021-08-03T13%3A15%3A30Z
```

but the response returns dates in the format below, which I need to pass back in to make another request (to handle pagination)

```
2021-08-03T09:17:42.087726-04:00
```

What I am trying to get out of this question:

a)confirm that the difference in the two dates are ecnoded vs decoded b) how to encode / decode a date
c) confirm that is a common practice in api requests

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: a)confirm that the difference in the two dates are ecnoded vs decoded b) how to encode / decode a date c) confirm that is a common practice in api requests

Comment: You should edit your question and add it there. :)

Comment: Try `from urllib.parse import quote, unquote` and then check `unquote('%5Bgt%5D=2021-08-03T13%3A15%3A30Z')` as well as  `quote('2021-08-03T09:17:42.087726-04:00')`.

Comment: Ty for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decode a `datetime` from a `str` you need to use [datetime.fromisoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) function.

And to encode a date (i.e. from `datetime` object to `str`), use [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).